To batch rename files so that spaces will be replaced with underscores
Is it possible to batch rename files in Fish so that the spaces will be replaced with underscores?
I tried to figure it out myself, but haven't succeeded yet: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/string.html#replace-literal-examples.
I tried things like
for file in *; mv $file $file | string replace -a ' ' '_'; end

but neither solution worked for me.

There may be more idiomatic ways of renaming in fish that I'm not aware of, however your loop approach will work if you put the string replace inside a command substitution:
# fish 3.1.0 or newer
for file in *\ *
  mv -n -- $file (
    string replace -a -- ' ' _ $file |
      string collect
  )
end

Note the piping to string collect (requires fish 3.1.0 or newer) to prevent the splitting that is otherwise done on newline characters so it can be done on arbitrary file names. Trailing newline characters (the one added by string replace but also the ones found at the end of the file names if any) are lost though.
Recent versions of fish (3.4.0 or newer) have now added support for the $(...) Korn-style form of command substitution, which can be used inside double quotes, preventing the splitting and removing the need for string collect:
# fish 3.4.0 or newer
for file in *\ *
  mv -n -- $file "$(string replace -a -- ' ' _ $file)"
end

Preserving the trailing newlines in the file names if any can be achieved by working with NUL-delimited strings:
# fish 3.5.0 or newer
for file in *\ *
  mv -n -- $file (
    string join0 -- $file |
      string replace -a ' ' _ |
      string split0
  )
end

Though, if you're replacing spaces with underscores, chances are you'd likely also want to replace other whitespace characters (including newline aka \n) with underscore, which could just be:
for file in *
  set new (string replace -ra -- '\s' _ $file) &&
    mv -n -- $file $new 
end

(replaces only ASCII space, \r, \n, \t, \v, \f) or:
for file in *
  set new (string replace -ra -- '(*UCP)\s' _ $file) &&
    mv -n -- $file $new 
end

To match other characters classified as whitespace by Unicode (including things like the non-breaking space, the ideographic space and a few dozen more) based on Unicode Character Properties.
Replace *\ * with {.,}*\ * (* with {,.}*) to also process hidden files.

Thank you very much!

@StéphaneChazelas Hello, Stéphane. Are you sure the sentence "Trailing newline characters (the one added by string replace but also the ones found at the end of the file names if any are lost though)." is really complete? And is the part "There may be more idiomatic ways of renaming in fish that I'm not aware of" from the original version of the answer still relevant?

@jsx97, the closing ) was misplaced which I've fixed. I'm not a fish user so I don't know either whether that's the best way to do it. My edit was just to make it more reliable.

rename
This way is not particular to fish. Probably the easiest way for renaming multiple files is using Perl's rename. To translate spaces to underscores, you'd:
rename 'y/ /_/' *

If the files are also in subdirs you can use globstar or find:
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.jpg" -execdir rename "y/ /_/" {} +

References

Based on this answer
Howto: Linux Rename Multiple Files At a Shell Prompt – nixCraft
More info about y/, translate instead of substitute.
DistroTube - Tools For Renaming Files In Linux

